# How could I resize/scale a geojson polygon

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I'm currently building different geojson polygon interactions. 
My blocker is building this algorithm that allows to scale the size of the polygon with onMouseDown method.

It was built with vanilla.js and use npm for dependencies.

```
import distance from "@turf/distance";
import centroid from "@turf/centroid";
import transformScale from "@turf/transform-scale";
import EventEmitter from "events";
const emitter = new EventEmitter();

const ScaleMode = {
  scalestart(selectedFeature, originalCenter) {},
  scaling(selectedFeature, originalCenter, lastMouseDown) {},
  scaleend(selectedFeature) {},

  onSetup: function(opts) {
    var state = {};

    emitter.addListener(
      "scalestart",
      function() {
        this.scalestart(state.selectedFeature, state.originalCenter);
      }.bind(this)
    );
    emitter.addListener(
      "scaling",
      function() {
        this.scaling(
          state.selectedFeature,
          state.originalCenter,
          state.lastMouseDownLngLat
        );
      }.bind(this)
    );
    emitter.addListener(
      "scaleend",
      function() {
        this.scaleend(state.selectedFeature, state.lastMouseDownLngLat);
      }.bind(this)
    );

    state.selectedFeature = opts.selectedFeature || false;
    state.lastMouseDownLngLat = false;
    state.originalCenter = false;
    state.mode = "scale" || false;
    return state;
  },
  toDisplayFeatures(state, geojson, display) {
    display(geojson);
  },
  onMouseDown: (state, e) => {
    if (e.featureTarget) {
      // calculate the polygon center
      state.polyCenter = turf.centroid(e.featureTarget);
      const polyCoordinates = state.polyCenter.geometry.coordinates;
      const poly = turf.polygon(PolyData);
      console.log(poly);
      const scaledPoly = turf.transformScale(poly, 3);
      console.log(poly);

      // scaling
      state.scaledPoly = transformScale(poly, 3);

      // disable on drag map over the polygon
      e.target["dragPan"].disable();
    }
  }
};

export default ScaleMode;
```

I want to be able to increase the coordinates of the polygon using onMouseDown/onMouseUp/onDrag methods.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/54qv8x244n

Comment: You'd need to create `mapbox-gl-draw-scale-mode` before you could use it. The good news is you can get inspiration from [mapbox-gl-draw-rotate-mode](https://github.com/mapstertech/mapbox-gl-draw-rotate-mode/blob/master/dist/mapbox-gl-draw-rotate-mode.min.js). Please note your question is asking for several hours of coding (from someone highly proficient). In theory, anything exceeding 15 minutes of effort is considered *off-topic* on [SO] for being too broad.

Comment: You might want to clone the rotate module and modify it to perform a transform. If you run into any trouble, ask about that specific challenge and document what makes you believe what you've done should work.

Comment: If you could see, I'm using mapbox-gl-rotate-mode. The issue that I have know is with scaleTransform of turf. They return like polygon is undefined (?)

Comment: The `scaleTransform` should be performed on `onDrag`, not on `onMouseDown`. When pressing mouse you save current centroid and the distance to current point, to compare it with the distance from centroid to current point `onDrag` and determine the transform scale. `onMouseUp` should be used for cleanup. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clone of `mapbox-gl-rotate-mode` handling `scaleTransform`:

```js
const distance = require("@turf/distance").default;
const centroid = require("@turf/centroid").default;
const transformScale = require("@turf/transform-scale").default;
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const emitter = new EventEmitter();

var ScaleMode = {
  scalestart: function() {},
  scaling: function() {},
  scaleend: function() {},

  onSetup: function(opts) {
    var state = {};

    emitter.addListener(
      "scalestart",
      function() {
        this.scalestart(state.selectedFeature, state.originalCenter);
      }.bind(this)
    );
    emitter.addListener(
      "scaling",
      function() {
        this.scaling(
          state.selectedFeature,
          state.originalCenter,
          state.scaleFactor
        );
      }.bind(this)
    );
    emitter.addListener(
      "scaleend",
      function() {
        this.scaleend(state.selectedFeature, state.scaleFactor);
      }.bind(this)
    );

    state.selectedFeature = opts.selectedFeature || undefined;
    state.scaleFactor = 1;
    state.originalCenter = undefined;
    state.mode = "scale";
    return state;
  },

  onMouseDown: function(state, e) {
    if (e.featureTarget) {
      if (this._ctx.api.get(e.featureTarget.properties.id)) {
        e.target["dragPan"].disable();
        state.selectedFeature = this._ctx.api.get(
          e.featureTarget.properties.id
        );
        state.originalCenter = centroid(e.featureTarget);
        state.originalFeature = e.featureTarget;
        state.originalDistance = Math.max(
          distance(state.originalCenter, [e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat]),
          0.1
        );
        emitter.emit("scalestart");
      }
    }
    return state;
  },

  toDisplayFeatures: function(state, geojson, display) {
    display(geojson);
  },

  onDrag: function(state, e) {
    if (state.selectedFeature && state.mode) {
      if (state.mode === "scale") {
        switch (state.originalFeature.properties["meta:type"]) {
          case "Point":
            break;
          case "LineString":
          case "Polygon":
          case "MultiLineString":
          case "MultiPolygon":
            state.scaleFactor =
              distance(state.originalCenter, [e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat]) /
                state.originalDistance || 1;
            break;
          default:
            return;
        }
        emitter.emit("scaling");
        state.selectedFeature.geometry = transformScale(
          state.originalFeature,
          state.scaleFactor
        ).geometry;
        this._ctx.api.add(state.selectedFeature);
      }
    }
  },

  onMouseUp: function(state, e) {
    e.target["dragPan"].enable();
    emitter.emit("scaleend");
    state.selectedFeature = undefined;
    state.scaleFactor = undefined;
    state.originalCenter = undefined;
    state.originalDistance = undefined;
    return state;
  }
};

module.exports = ScaleMode;
```

I wrapped it up as a npm package and you can now use it exactly like the rotate plugin:

```
npm i mapbox-gl-scale-mode
```

See it [working here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zk73237p84).